# string split method (each in line) javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a code for a program that allow the user to enter a word or sentnce in text-box then press the button.

When the user press the button the result should appear

actually I faced a problem in last part which is split the sentence and put each in separate line.

What I know is that I can put them in separate line by write a code such that:

```
var myString = "zero one two three four";

var mySplitResult = myString.split(" ");

for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
    document.write("<br /> Element " + i + " = " + mySplitResult[i]); 
}
```

but when I did it, it didn't work

my code

```
 function t {
    var r=input.split(".");
             for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
        r.innerHTML ="<br/> "  + r[i];}
          }
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write` I would recommend using [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for templating.

Comment: @Web_Designer: No need for a templating system when just learning JavaScript. And the full code acutally isn't using it anymore, but correclty assigns to a `innerHTML` from the click listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
>     result.innerHTML = "Lenrth of input string:  "+ input.length
>       + "<p>Number of spaces:  "+num +"</p>"
>       + "<p> Replacing the word 'red' with 'blue':  "+ input.replace("red" , "blue")+"</p>"
>       + "<p>Spilting at'.':</p><br/> " + n[i];
> }
> ```

This way, you will assign to `result.innerHTML` and overwrite it *each loop turn* - so the output you will notice is only the one from the last loop turn. Instead, you should build a html string part-by-part (including the repetion), and then assign the whole thing.

```
var html = "<p>Length of input string: " + input.length + "</p>";
html += "<p>Number of spaces: " + num + "</p>";
html += "<p> Replacing the word 'red' with 'blue': " + input.replace("red" , "blue") + "</p>";
html += "<p>Spilting at '.':<ul>";
for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    html += "<li>" + n[i] + "</li>";
}
html += "</ul></p>";
result.innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your result.innerHTML with each iteration of the for loop

Try making a var str to hold your computed string and iterate over that in the for loop.

> str += "Lenrth of input string:  "+ input.length +"
>
> Number of
>   spaces:  "+num +"
>
> "
>            +"
>
> Replacing the word 'red' with 'blue':  "+ input.replace("red" , "blue")+"
>
> Spilting at'.':
>
> "+
>            "
>  "  + n[i];

Then outside the for loop

> result.innerHTML = str

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is replacing the content on each iteration. You need to make your for loop only append the elements of n to the innerHTML of the result element.

```
function F1()
{  
  var str =document.getElementById("text");
  var input =  str.value;
  var result = document.getElementById( "result" );
  var num =  input.split(" ").length - 1;
  var n=input.split(".");

  result.innerHTML = "Lenrth of input string:  "+ input.length +"<p>Number of spaces:  "+num +"</p>"
  +"<p> Replacing the word 'red' with 'blue':  "+ input.replace("red" , "blue")+"</p><p>Spilting at'.':</p>";

  for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
    result.innerHTML += "<br/> "  + n[i];
  }
}
```

Here's a working example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nQ39D/